# My consumer group is stuck in rebalancing and does not consume v0.11 kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

My consumer group is not consuming data from the topic from the kafka cluster v 0.11

It starts up and it does not process messages from the topic. I see the following logs:

```
Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.222 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-9-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.222 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.222 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-5-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.222 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-7-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.227 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-7-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.227 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-5-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.227 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.227 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-9-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.227 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-3-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-5-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-7-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-9-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-7-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-5-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-9-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-3-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.228 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.233 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.234 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.234 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.234 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.269 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-6-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.270 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-6-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.270 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-6-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.270 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-6-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.396 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.397 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.398 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.398 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.521 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.522 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.522 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-4-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.522 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-4-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.522 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-8-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator xxxx:9097 (id: 2147477640 rack: null) for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new.
2019-07-24 11:25:08.523 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-8-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new
2019-07-24 11:25:08.523 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-8-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2019-07-24 11:25:08.524 Level=INFO 47637 --- [ntainer#0-8-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group cs-ms-mapping-processor-dev-new


I also see this log:
Auto-commit of offsets {cs-ms-notification-prod-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=401005946, metadata=''}} failed for group cs-ms-mapping-processor-prod-new: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records
```

```
max-poll-records: 1
session.timeout.ms: "450000"
request.timeout.ms: "480000"
max.poll.interval.ms: "450000"
```

code snippet

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.notification.topic-name:notification}", containerFactory = NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    public void accept(KafkaStatusMessage kafkaStatusMessage) {
        ContentId contentId = kafkaStatusMessage.getHeaders();
        StatusInfo statusInfo = kafkaStatusMessage.getCurrentStatus();
        List<StatusInfo> previousStatuses = kafkaStatusMessage.getPreviousStatuses();
}

DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, KafkaStatusMessage> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                jsonDeserializer);
```

This are the config values I have right now

I would like it to consume messages from the topic but its not doing so

Comment: Do you have any timestamps with the associated logs ? Could you share the part of your code when you do consume ?

Comment: @Yannick I have updated the post with timestamps and sample code used. I see the consumer not consuming the messages from the topic. All the other consumer groups are reading messages successfully, its only this consumer group thats unable to read the message. I assume its the timeout settings?

Comment: when I describe the consumer group using the cli, I get this `Warning: Consumer group 'cs-ms-mapping-processor-int' is rebalancing.` and don't see the consumer id for the partitions

Comment: What's the 'ntainer#0-4-C-1' means? Seems that the ID change at a point, like new instances started, you don't have any other error message in your app? Something crashing or timing out?

Comment: That's just part of the thread names that poll their corresponding consumer. It looks like you have 10 consumers in the app. Maybe take a look at the server logs to see if there are any clues there as to why the rebalance occurred?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the server log. I see the consumption either pretty slow or not all and rebalancing happens often

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We were able to figure the issue and this corresponds some error in the app with is not related to Kafka.Thanks all for your help.